# Where can I get the native implementation for a specific IL instruction?

Tags: sscli

I want to take a look at the implementation of a certain IL instruction, for example, `box`, in SSCLI, where can I get it in the SSCLI 2.0 source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the implementation

```
C:\Users\preet\Downloads\sscli20_20060311\sscli20\clr\src\vm\methodtable.cpp(1933):OBJECTREF MethodTable::Box(void* data, BOOL mayContainRefs)
```

Comment: I don't seem to have C:\Users\preet :)?